# Content Query Web Part Not Showing Custom Content Types

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

In my SharePoint 2013 environment I have custom content type deployed in a specified custom group.  The group and content type is visible on the site collection's content types page.

On the home page I have dropped a content editor web part and noticed that my content type group is not visible in the dropdown for configuring the query.

What other configurations are necessary for this content type and group to be visible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit counter intuitive but I discovered you must first pick a List Type first for some reason.  Doing so displayed my content type and group.